# Gandi Python instance : How to run several web sites with git and wsgi

Tags: django, git, web-hosting, wsgi

I want to run several Django web sites on a Gandi Python instance (Simple Hosting).
From what I've understood on their wiki ([here](https://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/git) and [here](https://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/instance/python)) I have only one virtual host and one git repository available for all domains.

When asked, Gandi's support told me that to deploy my sites with git, I can use branches for each site and use the command `$ ssh {login}@git.{datacenter_location}.gpaas.net 'deploy default.git [ {a_branch} ]'`.
I don't really think that's the proper way of using branches... 
Is there a better way ? If not, I have to create a repo on top of my local sites and a branch for each one ?
**Edit:** Thanks too [Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324033/sayse)'s comment, I know that I can't use git for several sites if I have only one repo. Now the wsgi part :

Then what to put in wsgi.py at the root of my vhost to root to the right site depending on the domain ? Maybe something like this ? :

```
import sys
import socket
import os.path
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

current host = socket.gethostname()

if current_host == "www.site_1.com":
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'site_1/site_1')))
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "site_1.settings")
elif current_host == "www.site_2.com":
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'site_2/site_2')))
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "site_2.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I'm new to python sites deployment, thanks by advance for your help !

Comment: Your question is too broad... but that, categorically, is the incorrect way to use git and branches, if the websites are completely separate entities then treat them as such

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get your point, how to treat them separately under only one repo then ?

Comment: That is my point, they shouldnt be in the same repo.

Comment: Ok thanks. So there's no clean way, I just can't use git then :/ Am I wrong too for the wsgi part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per their Python documentation :

"Python instances support only one application per instance"

So you would only have one branch that contains all of the websites you want to host. Then as you're attempting to do in your code above, route the traffic in your wsgi.py based on the HOST request header.

This has a major downside for what you're trying to do, namely, if you need to update one site you're going to have to redeploy the entire code based for all the websites. You're likely better off with separate instances for each site.

socket.gethostname() <- this is the wrong thing to use. This gets the hostname of the server Python is running on. You need to obtain the HTTP HOST header from the request.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/